# Change "go back" button label accordingly to the last page visited with react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I'm trying to implement a go back button using react-router-dom. The button works fine, but my problem is to change its label accordingly to the last page visited.
This button will appear only in one specific component that can be accessed from two different pages.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

export const GoBack = ({ label }) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => history.goBack()}>{label}</button>
    </div>
  )
};
```

Cheers!

Comment: why are you making seperate componenet just for goBack ?

Comment: why can't you pass the props with boolean to handle your case?

Comment: like I said => This button will appear only in **one specific component** that can be **accessed from two different pages**.  I need to know from which of these pages the user came from. @RaghulShree

Comment: did you exactly want the previous URL from which page users comes you can use " document.referrer " , check it will work in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your current location like this:
using `Link`

```js
<Link to="/next" state={{ prevPath: this.props.location.pathname }}> Your Next path</Link>`
```

pushing history:

```js
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: '/next',
  state: { prevPath: this.props.location.pathname }
})
```

Don't forget to wrap your component with `withRouter`(this.props.location wont be available otherwise).
Now you can get prevPath inside next component

```js
componentDidMount(){
    const{prevPath}=this.props.location.state;   //I think it here but google to make sure
    this.setState({
        prevPath
    })
}
```

Now you can conditionRender your button:

```js
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            {this.state.prevPath=="yourrequiredprevpath"&&<button>go johnny go</button>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

I strongly feel there is a better and more stable answer to your question but since no one answered this will keep you going until you find it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @saeed
I'll try to give it a go.